# \rule's alignment

Tags: vertical-alignment, rules, parameters

I would like to use `\rule` (or something that looks similar) to do separations in a CV but I don't quite understand how it works.

So far I came up with the following.

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        %\vspace*{0.075\textheight}
        {\huge \textsc{Curriculum Vitae} } \\[0.5cm]
    \end{center}
    \textbf{Full Name:} Mister BEAN\\
    \textbf{Date and place of birth:} February 30, 1968, England


    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}\\


\end{document}
```

I would like the `\rule`'s to be aligned with some text (in this case "Full Name" and "Date and place of birth"), but for some reasons, only the second one is at the right position.

Is the global format wrong or do I have to play with the parameters of `\rule`? If it's the latest, what are the parameters that I can use for different alignments?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The first `\hrule` starts a new paragraph. The solution is simple: add `\noindent` in front of the first `\hrule`.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to get is that a `\rule`, like so many other LaTeX commands, creates a box that behaves in just about every respect like a letter. In this case, a very oddly shaped one, but a letter anyhow. In particular, it starts a new paragraph.

Try on these for size:

```
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}\par
\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}\par
```

I put an explict `\par` at the end, rather than just a blank line, to make explicit the need to end the paragraph here. Though visually, in this particular case, the first one has no effect other than inserting `\parskip` glue between the rules. But if the sum of their lengths had been less, they might both have ended up on the same line.